# android emulator speed fast but cpu still 100%

Tags: android, android-emulator

I installed android sdk on ubuntu and execute android under **../tools like:
./android**

Then I installed android-19 level packages. After that I created emulator and its configuration is shown below:

```
Device: nexus 5
Target: android 4.4.2- api level 19
CPU/ABI: intel atom x86
memory: 1024
vm heap: 64
internal storage 200
```

Note: I m using **kvm**.

My emulator speed is not problem. But why cpu usage is 100%. 
Is it about GPU or another setting about phone?

Comment: Your question is geared more towards your computing hardware not the emulator itself.

Comment: I did not say that the problem is about emulator. I declared the problem and try to find the answer

Comment: I have same problem. Does anyone have a solution???